# SQL: Joining two tables with ids and counts

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I have stuck in one query and can't find a solution for that. I have two tables. One is the about the users and the other one is about the spenders. Below are the examples of the tables:

user table:

```
date ___ user_id ____ country 
2020 ___ ara123  _____ canada
2019 ___ ara567 ______ USA
2018 ___ ara890 ______ USA
2017 ___ ara789 ______ canada
```

spender table:

```
date ___ spender_id ____ country ___ gross_spend ___ net spend 
2020 ___ ara123  _____ Canada.   ___ 3.4 ___________ 4.5
2019 ___ ara567 ______ USA _________ 4.5 ___________ 6.7
2018 ___ abcd34 ______ USA _________ 56.5 __________ 4.3
```

I am trying to join these two tables in a way that I can make two calculations and add them to the final table. The first calculation is the sum(gross_spend)/count(user_ids) and the other one is (gross_spend)/(spender_id). I also need to do the left join to have all of the user_ids and the common ids from the spender id. However, when I join these two tables, the results of both of these calculations came out the same. Below is the table that I am looking for:

```
date ___ user_id ____ spender_id ____ country ___ cal1 ____ cal2
2020 ___ ara123 _____ ara123    _____ Canada ____ 0.85 ____ 1.7
2019 ___ ara567 _____ ara567   _______ USA ____ 1.126 ___ 2.25
2018 ___ara890 ______ NULL ___________ USA ____ NULL ____ NULL 
2017 ___ ara789 ______NULL ___________ canada ___NULL ___NULL
```

I have tried the following query:

```
select a.date, a.user_id, b.spender_id, a.country, 
      (b.gross_spend)/count(distinct a.user_id),
      (b.gross_spend)/count(distinct b.spender_id)
from user_table a
LEFT JOIN spender_table b
on a.date = b.date and a.user_id = b.spender_id -- have also tried without joining on second condition
group by 1,2,3,4
```

The problem that I have is that for the cal1 and cal2 columns, all the values are becoming the same. It works find when I only add the date, cal1 and cal2. However, once I add the spender_id and user_id to the tables, it causes this problem. Do you know how I can fix it? The ids have to be in the tables.
Thank you!

Comment: your example is oversimplified. your first cal1 row assumes there are 4 (3.4/0.85) users but you only showed one in 2020. your query is correct for what it's worth if you used the complete data set; with the provided data set cal1 and cal2 should equal to each other- there is either one or no records to divide by in all cases

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by the individual user_id and spender_ids and when you do that, the count(distinct user_id/spender_id) will always be 1.